# Why do AC/DC power supplies need cooling while transformers operating at similar power levels don't?

Tags: transformer, ac-dc

I will be running a 110 volt to 6.3 volt transformer that delivers 65 watts. I usually see these types of transformers in home appliances and guitar amplifiers with no active cooling. Why do these transformers not need cooling while an AC to DC power supply delivering similar power usually have a fan?

Comment: My laptop has a 65 watt smps that has no active cooling, and is smaller than most 65 watt power line transformers

Comment: Hunks of copper and iron are more resistant to high temperature than semiconductors.

Comment: _"an AC to DC power supply delivering similar power **usually** have a fan?"_ - Google disagrees. Typical 65W internal DC power supply, "Cooling by free air convection":- https://docs.rs-online.com/c580/0900766b814f2913.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Every electronic or electric part with some thermal losses needs some cooling. If you would enclose them with a thick styrofoam box they would overheat and be destroyed after some tens minutes up to some hours.

Each of those parts has a certain heat loss due to efficiency, a maximum temperature and a surface to transfer heat to the air.

A transformer has a good efficiency and the maximum temperature of the winding may be very high, about 150 to 180 °C. The surface of a 65 watt transformer is sufficient to transfer the heat to the air without a blower.

The efficiency of a linear non switched AC to DC power supply is much worse and the semiconductors maximum temperature may be 100 °C or less. If it is build with a small surface it needs a fan. Of course you can mount the semiconductors on a very large heat sink at the surface of the case and need no fan at all.

Compact high power transformers rated for some 100 kW may need a fan when enclosed within a building. A outdoor version for the same power would stay cool without a fan.